# Why are my ports not being mapped in docker-compose?

Tags: python, docker, flask

I currently have a small api written in Flask made for interacting with a CNN, I'm setting up the configuracion for running it in Docker and everything runs fine, this is my actual configuration:

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:2.7.15-jessie
RUN mkdir -p usr/src/app
COPY . usr/src/app
WORKDIR usr/src/app
RUN which python
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y
RUN pip install flask flask_uploads Werkzeug opencv-python numpy tensorflow
ENV PORT 5000
EXPOSE 5000
CMD ["flask", "run"]
```

Docker-compose:

```
version: "2.2"
services:
  api:
    container_name: "pyserver"
    build: .
    volumes:
      - ".:/usr/src/app"
    environment:
      FLASK_APP: server.py
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    command: ["flask", "run"]
```

server.py

```
import os
from base64 import b64encode, b64decode
from flask import Flask, redirect, request, url_for, json, send_file
from flask_uploads import UploadSet, configure_uploads
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
from GW_predict import predict

UPLOAD_FOLDER = 'CNN/Files'
ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = set(['txt', 'csv', 'png', 'jpg', 'jpeg'])

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER
app.config["DEBUG"] = True

def allowed_file(filename):
    ext = '.' in filename and \
           filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower()
    return ext, ext in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS

@app.route('/status', methods=['GET'])
def status():
    return create_response({ 'online': True, 'message': 'UP AND RUNNING @ 5000' }, 200)

@app.route('/uploadFile', methods=['POST'])
def upload_file():
    if 'h1' not in request.files or 'l1' not in request.files:
        return create_response({'result': False, 'message': 'File missing'}, 422)

    h1_file = request.files['h1']
    l1_file = request.files['l1']

    if h1_file.filename == '' or l1_file.filename == '':
        return create_response({'result': False, 'message': 'File missing'}, 422)

    h1_ext, h1res = allowed_file(h1_file.filename)
    l1_ext, l1res = allowed_file(l1_file.filename)

    if h1_file and l1_file and h1res and l1res:
        h1_filename = secure_filename(h1_file.filename)
        l1_filename = secure_filename(l1_file.filename)
        h1 = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], h1_filename)
        l1 = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], l1_filename)
        h1_file.save(h1)
        l1_file.save(l1)
        # img = b64encode((open(img, "rb").read()))
        if h1_ext == 'png' and l1_ext == 'png':
            result = predict(h1, l1)
            return create_response({'result': True, 'prediction': result}, 200)

        return create_response({'result': False, 'message': 'Images format must be png'}, 422)

    return create_response({'result': False, 'message': 'No allowed file'}, 422)

def create_response(message, status):
    response = app.response_class(
        response= json.dumps(message),
        status= status,
        mimetype='application/json'
    )
    return response

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

The problem is that in my docker-compose file I have configured the "ports" instruction in which I define to expose de port 5000 in my host and to forward to the same port in the container.

This does not work.

Inside the container I can make the request via CURL to the endpoint, but outside of the container I am unable to do so. What could be wrong?

Comment: What does `docker ps` show?

Comment: Nothing :/, but `docker ps -a` shows this: > `06bd82268dc9        cnn_api             "flask run"              22 minutes ago      Up 4 seconds                   0.0.0.0:5000->5000/tcp   pyserver`

Comment: can you share code you use for curl that works inside container and the one that doesn't work outside. Also, can you confirm that on host you don't have 5000 already taken?

Comment: What interfaces is your app listening on inside the container? See the [netstat usage with netshoot](https://github.com/nicolaka/netshoot/blob/master/README.md) for how to check this without installing networking tools inside your image.

Comment: @Const inside: `curl http://localhost:5000/status`, outside: `curl http://localhost:5000/status`, `curl http://127.0.0.1:5000/status` none of them (outside) work

Comment: @BMitch only tcp:5000, nothing else

Comment: I'm not following, tcp: 5000 is not an interface, please include the full output.

Comment: Sorry @BMitch for the bad answer. What do you mean by interface?

Comment: Your looking for something like a 0.0.0.0 or 127.0.0.1, or maybe ::1 in the output with the port number. When the app inside the container listens on 127.0.0.1, port forwarding from outside the container can't reach it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe you need to specify the `--host=0.0.0.0` flag? (from [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/quickstart/)).

Can you try to override your `command` in docker-compose?

```
version: "2.2"
services:
  api:
    container_name: "pyserver"
    build: .
    command: flask run --host=0.0.0.0
    volumes:
      - ".:/usr/src/app"
    environment:
      FLASK_APP: server.py
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    command: ["flask", "run"]
```

By the  way, not sure that the `EXPOSE` in dockerfile is necessary if you are communicate only from your host machine (rather than other container).

Comment: Pretty sure this is it (hence my comment asking about interfaces). If flask defaults to loopback, you can't reach it from outside. You can also `app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port='5000')` in the python script.

Comment: @BMitch right, just trying to give a fast solution to see if this is it..

Comment: And this was it! Thank you man. Adding the flag made it work.

Comment: Per your expose comment, it's not needed for anything other than documentation. It has no effect on the behavior of docker networking when publishing ports or communicating between containers.

Comment: Yeah, I know it does not do anything besides documentation. Thanks for your time man! @BMitch